# Add project library error when close project properties?

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

I work with eclipse and I would like to use from external project library some class. Every time I open project properties add this external project I get following problem. There is no problems with another project libraries. This additional project has ticked "Is Library".
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to import an Android library is :

1. import your library projects to your workspace
2. right click your main project and properties
3. close to the top, choose Android [image]
4. Then click add from the library section at the bottom